# How to realise relationship Django ORM model with multiple fields of another one?

Tags: database, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

In one of my projects, I came across the need to have a relationship **of one model** with one of several fields ** of another model**. I do not know how to do this, because if I just refer from two attributes through the same Foreign Key using one related_name, I have errors

Here is a similar example. There is a table with films and their directors. And also each user can share his opinion and indicate **one** the best and **one** the worst movie in his opinion. At the same time, they should be different films.

The bottom line is that I want out of the `Movie` model I could get all mentions of a certain movie. That is, `movie.rates.all()` and would get a QuerySet of all the rates of this movie, the worst and the best.

How to implement it?

```py
from django.db import models


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director', related_name='movies', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   

class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    

class MovieRate(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # best = 
    # worst =
```